# Is there a Stack Exchange site for environment questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm aware of [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) which is clearly related, but the scope seems restricted to scientific questions. As  far as I understand it wouldn't fit for for practical questions (e.g., about how to recycle X), right?

What about questions about policy or energy consumption, for instance? I'm aware that a new site could be proposed in Area 51, I'm just checking in case I missed the relevant site.

Comment: [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) might be useful to you depending on your exact question. Be sure to check their [help page](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make sure your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sustainable Living.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) and [Earth Science.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) are the closest. Other Stack Exchange sites may accept environment questions if on topic (I know it's a tautology), e.g. [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) for some policies, and [Data Science.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) for energy consumption from GPUs if used for data science.